# Issue with transferring a double property from C++ To C# with Google Protocol Buffer and Protobuf-C#

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, qpid

I am attempting to send an object as a serialized string from C++ to C# over QPID which is a messaging system. I currently have a Google proto file as such:

```
package Serializable;

message Order_ser 
{
    optional  int32 openord = 1 [default = 0];
    optional  int32 oldord = 2 [default = 0]; 
    optional  double price = 3 [default = 0];
}
```

I get the error at C# end when transferring the object through C++

```
Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
```

This only happens if i assign a value to a double type such as price.

Comment: Encoding is such a common gotcha that I put together http://tiny.cc/io to cover this (and a few others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, I don't believe that `SerializeAsString` *really* converts it into text - so you shouldn't be treating it as text at the C# side. I strongly suspect that it's the interpretation of the binary data as UTF-8-encoded text which is going wrong.

I know nothing of QPID, but assuming you can transfer arbitrary *binary* messages that way, that's what you should do. If you *can't* transfer arbitrary binary messages over QPID, then Protocol Buffers may well not be an appropriate solution for you - they're really designed as an efficient binary representation. You could base64-encode the data of course, but you may well find there are more appropriate approaches.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet said, I would think SerializeAsString will return the protocol buffer in it's text representation (see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) i.e.

```
# Textual representation of a protocol buffer.
# This is *not* the binary format used on the wire.
person {
  name: "John Doe"
  email: "jdoe@example.com"
}
```

A simple write of the string will determine if this is correct. This format has no relation to the binary format so **can not** be deserialised you ar try to do.

The options (in best to worst order) are
* Serialise to byte Array and send / retrieve as bytes
* Serialise to byte Array and encode / decode byte Array as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) 
* Encode as String like you are doing and use the String-Deserialise.

I do not use C or C# so can not advise on the Code to use

Comment: Actually, I suspect this is *not* related to the *text format*, but rather it is referring to the C++ string meaning: "a set of bytes that is often used to store data that happens to be ASCII". The issue is the OP treating that as a *textual* string, when in this case the bytes are simply ***not*** ASCII.

Comment: could be correct, I have never used the C version of protocol buffers